# Foreign Key on a customized Users model Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I have the following 2 models `User` (customized) and `Activity`. A user can only be connected to 1 activity but an activity can be referenced from multiple `User` entries, thus, I have a Many-to-One relationship and I have created this relationship in the following way:

```
Task app
models.py

from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

class Task(models.Model):
    id          = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    responsible = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    task        = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=140)
    initial_date= models.DateField(default=timezone.now(), null=False)
    ending_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now(), null=False)

Accounts app
models.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager

class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, username, password=None):

        if not email:
            raise ValueError("User must have an email address.")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("User must have a username.")

        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email),username=username,)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):

        user = self.create_user(email=self.normalize_email(email),username=username,password=password,)
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email        = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
    username     = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)

    # The following fields are required for every custom User model
    last_login   = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    date_joined  = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    is_admin     = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active    = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff     = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email' 
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

I have done migrations but the relationship wth the FK is not successful and even when I try to do a simple queryset on the `Activity` model such as `q = Activity.objects.all()` I get `ProgrammingError: column activity_activity.responsible_id doesn't exist`. What step am I missing in this foreign key relationship with my customized `Users` model? Any help, comment or edit will be greatly appreciated :)

My desired result with the FK relationship

```
id | responsible |  task           | initial_date | ending_date
-------------------------------------------------------------
4  |  roger_785  | Refactor code   |   2020-01-16 |    None
5  |  mauro_12   | Fix the network |   2020-01-10 |    None
```

Comment: Your custom User class is named `Account` and You have FK to `User`?

Comment: I used the `User=get_user_model()` to refer to my custom User  class model.

Comment: The error says about `responsible_id` not existing on `activity` table while Your model is `Task`, is that a typo?

Comment: Good catch! I did the correction but still same results.

Comment: Have you set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in `settings.py` to point to the custom user model that you have written?

Comment: Yes, that’s already included in the settings.py of the main file.

Answer (score 0):

change the import User to:

```
from django.conf import settings 
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
```